# invalidHandler setDefault ignored in $.validator call -jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

When I set up some defaults for the jQuery Validation plugin by calling the $.validator setDefaults method, the errorPlacement method runs fine, though the invalidHandler function is completely ignored??  Why?

Note that I'm using jQuery UI tabs in this instance and validating a tab's individual fields (in a form) with a .valid() call, not complete form .validate() call.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Simplified code below:

```
(function( $ ) {
    //det up some site wide validator defaults
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        invalidHandler: function(error, validator) {
            console.log("InvalidHandler Test");
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo("#error_validation span#errorSummary");
            $("#error_validation").show();
        }
    });
    //small jQuery plugin for error handling in a jQuery UI tab
    //by http://bit.ly/bhH1n1
    $.fn.validateTab = function () {
        var isValid = true;
        $(this).find("input, select").each(function () {
            if (isValid) {
                isValid = $(this).valid();
            } else {
                $(this).valid();
            }
        });
        return false;
    };


    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('#addUserBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#addUser").validateTab();
    });

});
```

Comment: Can't seem to find your problem but you might want to [try this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) as an alternative.

Comment: A simple test shows this working: http://jsfiddle.net/kzDnx/2/. Do you notice anything different about what you're doing? Also, I noticed you are never executing the anonymous function you're creating. Is this a copy paste error or is it what your code is actually doing?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank-you! Forehead slapping moment.  Embarrasingly simple mix-up between an anonymous function and shorthand jquery document ready function.  Just to point out I was using a call to valid() here but you are quite right it does work.  I've refactored your code slightly to prove it:  http://jsfiddle.net/awhenderson/xUYFt/5/.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

i'm not really sure why its not working but i needed it so i fixed it myself, if you want replace the setDefaults in the plugin to this

```
setDefaults: function (settings) {
    var validator = $.data($("form")[0], "validator");
    var originalSettings = jQuery.validator.getDefaults();
    for (var key in settings) {
        if (settings[key]) {
            originalSettings[key] = settings[key];
        }
    }
    validator.settings = $.extend(true, {}, $.validator.defaults, originalSettings);
},
getDefaults: function () {
    var validator = $.data($("form")[0], "validator");
    return validator.settings;
},
```